# How to animate an items transparecy while it is moving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a dollar sign pup up and move up about 100px. The dollar sign should fade in then fade out while it is in the process of moving. I cannot figure this out. Here's what I'm using right now, which has a pause in between operations. I need no pause. Thanks!

```
$("#dollar1").animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: '480px'
                  }, 1000);
$("#dollar1").animate({
    opacity: 0,
    top: '440px'
                  }, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. Here's a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RCtq5/ (top values changes for easier viewing). What exactly do you need that this doesn't do?

Comment: @j08691 The problem is this... http://jsfiddle.net/RCtq5/1/... the dollar sign stops then continues. I want it to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this along the lines of the effect you're looking for: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RCtq5/2/)**.

jQuery:

```
$("#dollar1").animate({
    top: '200px'
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    queue: false
});
$("#dollar1").animate({
    opacity: 0
}, {
    duration: 500,
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
        $("#dollar1").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false,
            complete: function() {
                $("#dollar1").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, {
                    duration: 500,
                    queue: false
                });
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Yes! That looks good in the fiddle, but when I put it to my page, everything completely stops working and my site falls apart a little. I'll try a few things to get it working.

Comment: Actually I don't know what to try... What exactly is the `queue: false` doing? That might be messing up my other jQuery. Not sure.

Comment: Setting queue to false allows the animations to bypass the queue and run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery website:

`$("#dollar1").animate({opacity: 1, top: '480px'}, 1000).animate({opacity: 0, top: '440px'}, 1000);`

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: That's equivalent to what I am already doing. I need to perform the fade out while the item is in motion. This code still makes the item stop then continue.

Comment: So within the movement of 100px it needs to fade from 0 to 1 and then back to 0?

Comment: $("#dollar1").fadeOut(1000, 'swing', function(){ $(this).fadeIn(1000); });
That works for the fadeOut and fadeIn but I'm not sure how you can combine it with a movement. I know how to do it in plain JS though ;)

Comment: That didn't do anything for me.